# Evaluate $\int\left(\sqrt{4-x^2}+x\right)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm looking for simple way to solve

> $$\int\left(\sqrt{4-x^2}+x\right) \, dx$$

I tried substitute $x=2\sin u$ and then

$$\cdots =\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac 1 2x\sqrt{4-x^2}+2\arcsin (x/2)+c$$

I'm looking for **other** solution please

Comment: I think what you tried is the most elementary!

Comment: "Solve" is not the right word here.  "Evaluate" is.  ("Solve" is one of those words that people not very familiar with mathematical terminology use as a catch-all when they don't know what word to use.  It has legitimate uses as well.) $\qquad$

Comment: Partial integration, you get the original integral back plus a term proportional to the derivative of an arcsin. You can then bring the square root term to the other side and solve for the integral of it.

Comment: Do you know that $\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}=\arcsin t+C$? If so one can use an integration by parts argument. There is also a purely geometric argument, involving area of part of a circle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way forward is to integrate by parts with $u=\sqrt{4-x^2}$ and $v=x$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int \sqrt{4-x^2}\,dx&=x\sqrt{4-x^2}+\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\,dx\\\\
&=x\sqrt{4-x^2}+\int \frac{x^2-4+4}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\,dx\\\\
&=x\sqrt{4-x^2}-\int \sqrt{4-x^2}\,dx+4\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\,dx\\\\
2 \int \sqrt{4-x^2}\,dx&=x\sqrt{4-x^2}+4\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\,dx\\\\
\int \sqrt{4-x^2}\,dx&=\frac12 x\sqrt{4-x^2}+2\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac12 x\sqrt{4-x^2}+2\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(x/2)^2}}\,d(x/2)\\\\
&=\frac12 x\sqrt{4-x^2}+2\arcsin(x/2)+C
\end{align}$$